# how to enlarge images from slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have already asked a question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024225/how-to-enlarge-image-of-slider. But I did not get answer. Now I have found solution. It is working well. But I need to simplify the jquery which in bottom of this code. Please can anyone help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sss/sss.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.slider').sss();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php for($z=1;$z<3;$z++){;?>
<div class="MyBox<?php echo $z;?>" style="width:150px;height:200px;">
<div class="slider">
<img class="MyPhoto<?php echo $z;?>" src="MyPics/image1.jpg" style="height:200px;width:150px;"/>
<img class="MyPhoto<?php echo $z;?>" src="MyPics/image2.jpg" style="height:200px;width:150px;"/>
<img class="MyPhoto<?php echo $z;?>" src="MyPics/image3.jpg" style="height:200px;width:150px;"/>
</div>
</div>
<?php }?>
<script>

$(".MyBox1").on( "mouseover", function() {
    $(".MyBox1").css( "width", "+=400" );
    $(".MyBox1").css( "height", "+=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto1").css( "width", "+=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto1").css( "height", "+=400" );
});


$(".MyBox1").on( "mouseout", function() {
    $(".MyBox1").css( "width", "-=400" );
    $(".MyBox1").css( "height", "-=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto1").css( "width", "-=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto1").css( "height", "-=400" );

});

$(".MyBox2").on( "mouseover", function() {
    $(".MyBox2").css( "width", "+=400" );
    $(".MyBox2").css( "height", "+=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto2").css( "width", "+=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto2").css( "height", "+=400" );
});


$(".MyBox2").on( "mouseout", function() {
    $(".MyBox2").css( "width", "-=400" );
    $(".MyBox2").css( "height", "-=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto2").css( "width", "-=400" );
    $(".MyPhoto2").css( "height", "-=400" );

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The two MyBox's have the same JS. why declare them as separate classes?

Comment: if I put same class getting problem of another box when we call them another class also expanding. that's why I put separate class.

Comment: I have submitted my full code here and previous question. if you have any best way. please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the simplified jQuery version:

```
$(function(){

var myBox1 = $(".MyBox1"),
    myBox2 = $(".MyBox2"),
    myPhoto1 = $(".MyPhoto1"),
    myPhoto2 = $(".MyPhoto2");

 $(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.MyBox1, .MyBox2', function(e){

   var styleValue = (e.type === 'mouseover') ? "+=400" : "-=400";

   if( e.currentTarget.className == 'MyBox1' ){ 

     myBox1.css({
       "width" : styleValue,
       "height" : styleValue
     });

     myPhoto1.css({
       "width" : styleValue,
       "height" : styleValue
     });

   } else {

     myBox2.css({
       "width" : styleValue,
       "height" : styleValue
     });

     myPhoto2.css({
       "width" : styleValue,
       "height" : styleValue
     });
   }

 })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just enlarging something on hover, you can do this with pure CSS

```css
.MyBox {
  width:150px;
  height: 200px;
}

.MyBox:hover {
  width: 450px;
  height: 600px;
}

.MyPhoto {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

.MyPhoto:hover {
  height: 600px;
  width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="MyBox">
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="MyPhoto" src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <img class="MyPhoto" src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
    <img class="MyPhoto" src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for responding. But this hover is not working for all images. it is working for only the first image of the slider after that  the second image height is differing.